# program runs but errors out

Tags: cobol

I have this program that will compile but won't process. When I start the program to run it gets to line 148 "WRITE BASBALL-RECORD-OUT FROM HEADING-LINE-1" and says it was unhandled, how to I fix this. Thank you.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. BASEBALL-2.
      * Andrew Sawyer
      ******************************************************************
      * This program will sort different stats for different baseball
      * players with day, time, and muiltiple pages.
      ******************************************************************
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
 
       SELECT BASEBALL-FILE-IN
           ASSIGN TO 'BASEBALL-2.SEQ'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
 
       SELECT BASEBALL-FILE-OUT
           ASSIGN TO 'BASEBALL-2.RPT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
 
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  BASEBALL-FILE-IN.
   01 BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT          PIC 99.
   
   01 LINE-COUNT                   PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.
   
   01 WS-DATE.
       05  RUN-YEAR        PIC XX.
       05  RUN-MONTH       PIC XX.
       05  RUN-DAY         PIC XX.
   
   01  HEADING-LINE-1.
       05                  PIC X(24) VALUE SPACES.
       05                  PIC X(26) VALUE 'BASEBALL PLAYER STATS'.
       05                  PIC X(12) VALUE SPACES.
       05  HL-1-DATE.
           10  MONTH-2     PIC XX.
           10              PIC X       VALUE'/'.
           10  DAY-2       PIC XX.
           10              PIC X       VALUE'/'.
           10  YEAR-2      PIC XX.
       05                  PIC X(6)    VALUE SPACES.
       05  PAGE-1          PIC X(4)    VALUE 'PAGE'.
       
   01  HEADING-LINE-2.
       05                  PIC X(6)    VALUE 'LEAGUE'.
       05                  PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
       05                  PIC X(4)    VALUE 'TEAM'.
       05                  PIC X(5)    VALUE SPACES.
       05                  PIC X(4)    VALUE 'NAME'.
       05                  PIC X(10)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                  PIC X(4)    VALUE 'HITS'.
       05                  PIC X(6)    VALUE  SPACES.
       05                  PIC X(7)    VALUE 'AT-BATS'.
   
   FD  BASEBALL-FILE-OUT.
   01  DETAIL-LINE.
       05 BLANK-A-OUT      PIC X       VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-LEAGUE        PIC XX.
       05 BLANK-B-OUT      PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-TEAM          PIC X(3).
       05 BLANK-C-OUT      PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-NAME          PIC X(10).
       05 BLANK-D-OUT      PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-HITS          PIC ZZ9.
       05 BLANK-E-OUT      PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-AT-BATS       PIC ZZ9.
       
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.    
   01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS      PIC X(3)    VALUE 'YES'.
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.
       OPEN INPUT BASEBALL-FILE-IN
       OPEN OUTPUT BASEBALL-FILE-OUT
       
       ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE
       MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-2
       MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-2
       MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-2
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT FROM HEADING-LINE-1
       
       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO'
           READ BASEBALL-FILE-IN
               AT END
                   MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
               NOT AT END
                   PERFORM 200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM
 
       CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-IN
       CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-OUT
       STOP RUN.
 
   200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
       MOVE 'LEAGUE' TO DL-LEAGUE     
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-A-OUT
       MOVE 'TEAM' TO DL-TEAM    
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-B-OUT
       MOVE 'NAME' TO DL-NAME
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-C-OUT
       MOVE 'HITS' TO DL-HITS
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-D-OUT
       MOVE 'AT-BATS' TO DL-AT-BATS
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-E-OUT
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES.
           
   300-LINE.
       IF LINE-COUNT >= 50
          PERFORM 400-NEXT-PAGE
       END-IF
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
       AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT.
   
   400-NEXT-PAGE.
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING PAGE
       MOVE ZEROS TO LINE-COUNT
```

I am not sure if the program with print the data correctly, I am currently just trying to get it to compile. If there are any questions please ask.

Comment: You likely want to move `WORKING-STORAGE` up as all variables below the FD belong to the file as a different record-type, I guess you only want one record for the FD.

Comment: Your FILE SECTION has to contain both FD descriptions and one mand only one 01 record description for the input file and the output file, respectively.

Comment: can either of you show be in code?

Comment: You initially write *I have this program that will compile but won't process.*, then later on you write *I am currently just trying to get it to compile.* So, does it or does it not complie? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use an online COBOL compiler.  I was able to verify that this DATA DIVISION compiled.

The FILE SECTION comes first, then the WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.  I lined up the PIC and VALUE clauses so it's easier to read the code.

```
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD  BASEBALL-FILE-IN.
01  BASEBALL-RECORD-IN           PIC 99.

FD  BASEBALL-FILE-OUT.
01  BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT          PIC X(80).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 

01  LINE-COUNT                   PIC 99      VALUE ZEROS.
   
01  WS-DATE.
    05  RUN-YEAR                 PIC XX.
    05  RUN-MONTH                PIC XX.
    05  RUN-DAY                  PIC XX.
    
01  HEADING-LINE-1.
    05                           PIC X(24)   VALUE SPACES.
    05                           PIC X(26)   VALUE 'BASEBALL PLAYER STATS'.
    05                           PIC X(12)   VALUE SPACES.
    05  HL-1-DATE.
        10  MONTH-2              PIC XX.
        10                       PIC X       VALUE'/'.
        10  DAY-2                PIC XX.
        10                       PIC X       VALUE'/'.
        10  YEAR-2               PIC XX.
    05                           PIC X(6)    VALUE SPACES.
    05  PAGE-1                   PIC X(4)    VALUE 'PAGE'.
    
01  HEADING-LINE-2.
    05                           PIC X(6)    VALUE 'LEAGUE'.
    05                           PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
    05                           PIC X(4)    VALUE 'TEAM'.
    05                           PIC X(5)    VALUE SPACES.
    05                           PIC X(4)    VALUE 'NAME'.
    05                           PIC X(10)   VALUE SPACES.
    05                           PIC X(4)    VALUE 'HITS'.
    05                           PIC X(6)    VALUE  SPACES.
    05                           PIC X(7)    VALUE 'AT-BATS'.

01  DETAIL-LINE.
    05  BLANK-A-OUT              PIC X       VALUE SPACES.
    05  DL-LEAGUE                PIC XX.
    05  BLANK-B-OUT              PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
    05  DL-TEAM                  PIC X(3).
    05  BLANK-C-OUT              PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
    05  DL-NAME                  PIC X(10).
    05  BLANK-D-OUT              PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
    05  DL-HITS                  PIC ZZ9.
    05  BLANK-E-OUT              PIC X(3)    VALUE SPACES.
    05  DL-AT-BATS               PIC ZZ9.
    
01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS       PIC X(3)    VALUE 'YES'.
```